# CSR Format for sparse matrices having one row full of zeros

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

Can the following `3x3` sparse matrix be stored using `CSR` format in the Intel MKL library?

```
A = [ 0 0 1
      0 0 0
      3 1 4];

valuesA   = {1, 3, 1, 4};
columnsA  = {2, 0, 1, 2};
rowIndexA = {0, 1,      3};
```

How this can be differentiated from the following `2x3` matrix?

```
B = [ 0 0 1
      3 1 4];

valuesB   = {1, 3, 1, 4};
columnsB  = {2, 0, 1, 2};
rowIndexB = {0, 1,      3};
```

The reason, I have a row full of zero is matrix-indexing. This all-zero-row can happen anywhere in the matrix `A`. The matrix `A` is actually a sub-matrix of a bigger sparse matrix, which will be used in a system of equations `Ax = b`. Could someone kindly give me some insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the row is empty, just repeat the corresponding value in `rowIndexA`.

For the matrix

```
0 0 1
0 0 0
3 1 4
```

the correct representation is:

```
valuesA = {1, 3, 1, 4};
columnsA = {2, 0, 1, 2};
rowIndexA = {0, 1, 1, 4};
           //   ^^^^ repeat 1
```

The last value in `rowIndexA` should be equal to the number of elements, i.e. `4` in your case. Then you get the correct number of elements in each row: `1 - 0 = 1` in the first row, `1 - 1 = 0` in the second one and `4 - 1 = 3` in the last one.